Can't find variable in Shin y
I'm fairly new to Shiny and am running into the following issue where i can't find a variable
enter image description here
This is my UI...
ui <- {
  fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),
  
  tabsetPanel(      
    
    tabPanel("Time Series",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date1", 
                           label = "Select Date", 
                           choices = seq(from = as_date(now())-16, to = as_date(now())-1, by = "day")
               ),
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric1",
                           label = "Which Metric",
                           choices =   c("Login","Queue"))
               )
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("distPlot1")
             )
      ) 
    )
}


This is my server...
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  MyDT <- reactive({
    
    AbrQuery <- "

      SELECT 
          * 
      FROM SQ_ML_MODEL.dbo.DataSci_ABR_Preds_Vs_Actuals_updated
 
    "
    
    SecretValuesLst <- GetSecret(Debug = TRUE)
    
    print(SecretValuesLst)
    
    print(SecretValuesLst$SERVER)
    
    #===============================================================================
    
    connectionString <- paste0(
      "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=",SecretValuesLst$SERVER,
      ";Database=",SecretValuesLst$DATABASE,
      ";UID=",SecretValuesLst$UID,
      ";PWD=",SecretValuesLst$PWD, 
      ";TrustServerCertificate=yes;",
      sep="")
    
    DbCon <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)
    
    print(DbCon)
    
    #===============================================================================
    
    DataOutput <- RODBC::sqlQuery(DbCon, query = AbrQuery)
    
    DataOutput
    
    #===============================================================================
    ### 
    
    message("render_app_data: Prepare Data \n")
    
    # RawAbrData
    
    # str(RawAbrData)
    
    VizAbrData <- melt.data.table(DataOutput[, .(MinuteOfDay,
                                                 AgentCategory,
                                                 Queue,
                                                 Login,
                                                 Tier,
                                                 Abr_Actuals,
                                                 Abr_Preds,
                                                 Abr_Diff)],
                                  id.vars = c("MinuteOfDay",
                                              "AgentCategory"))
    
    VizAbrData
    
    # VizAbrData[, .N, by = variable]
    
    # VizAbrData[variable == "Login"]
    
    VizAbrData[, AsOfDate := as_date(MinuteOfDay)]
    
    # VizAbrData[, .N, by = AsOfDate]
    
    # WhichDates <- VizAbrData[order(-AsOfDate)][, unique(AsOfDate)][1:14]
    
    # WhichDates
    
    # VizAbrData <- VizAbrData[AsOfDate %in% WhichDates]
    
    # VizAbrData
    
    VizAbrData$value[is.na(VizAbrData$value)] <- 0
    
    # VizAbrData
    
    library(hms)
    
    VizAbrData[, MinuteOfDay_TIME := as_hms(MinuteOfDay)]
    
    mydat <- VizAbrData
    
    mydat[, AsOfDate := as.Date(AsOfDate)]
    
    mydat[, variable := as.character(variable)]
    
    #WhichDates <- mydat[, .N, by = AsOfDate][order(-AsOfDate)][1:10, AsOfDate]
    
    #WhichVariables <- mydat[, .N, by = variable][order(-variable)][1:10, variable]
    
  })
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
      subset(MyDT, 
                    AsOfDate %in% seq(from = as_date(now())-16, to = as_date(now())-1, by = "day") & 
                      variable %in% c("Login","Queue"))
    })
    
    ggplot(data = filtered_data_1(),
           aes(x = MinuteOfDay,
               y = value)) +
      geom_point(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
      geom_line(stat = "identity", linewidth = 1.6, col = "red") + 
      labs(x = "MinuteOfDay", y = input$Metric1) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Time Series: ", input$Metric1, sep = "")) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face= "bold", colour= "black", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
      )  +
      theme_classic()  
    
  })
}



I've seen posts where people say to add req() to the server section, but just looking for a clear sol8tion
Tried req, passing variables to the server, etvc

It would be helpful if you give the sample data for DataOutput  variable. You can simply do dput(DataOutput) in your R and paste the result in this question. With out the data its hard to resolve issue of your code.

I recommend moving the code that does the database query out of app.R into a .R script that defines various functions.  For example, query_database <- function(...) .  It's easier to test and debug outside of Shiny.  app.R can source() it.  I also recommend splitting into smaller functions: one for the query and another for the melt.  Also, does your function MyDT()reference theinput`s?  If not, perhaps it doesn't need to be a reactive function.
